# Malware advisory in Unity from Github?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm getting this set of error emails telling me that Unity might have been "fully compromised" It's coming from the official GitHub (not a fake, according to certification). I wanted to ask if this was an issue and if anyone else got it, as my friends that use unity didn't receive this email.

> Any computer that has this package installed or running should be
> considered fully compromised. All secrets and keys stored on that
> computer should be rotated immediately from a different computer. The
> package should be removed, but as full control of the computer may
> have been given to an outside entity, there is no guarantee that
> removing the package will remove all malicious software resulting from
> installing it.

[Emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGnAD.png)